# How can i check if user entering correct form of email

Tags: php

Well i am not using email verification so i am facing problem in checking correct form of email address

suppose if user enter `support` or `support@` it accept it as well.

So i atleast want them to enter there email or at least they enter email form correctly

**Here is my code:**

```
   <?php
    require_once 'global.php';
    if (!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
        header("Location: login.php");
    }
    $user    = unserialize($_SESSION['user']);
    $email   = $user->email;
    $message = "";
    if (isset($_POST['submit-settings'])) {
        $email       = $_POST['email'];
        $user->email = $email;
        $user->save();
        $msg = "Done!<br/>";
    }
    ?>
```

**Solved :**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit-settings'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    //  checking valid email
    if (!filter_var("$email", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $msg = "Wrong Email Setting Not Saved<br/>";
    } else {
        $user->email = $email;
        $user->save();
        $msg = "Settings Saved<br/>";
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple use filter_var() of PHP

```
if(filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  //email correct
}
else
{
 //email not correct
}
```