# PHP form sending error

Tags: php, regex, forms, email, contact-form

I will start off by saying I am not a coder and would really like some help.

My `contact.php` form keeps returning this error message:

```
Invalid email address entered
```

when I test it on a server.

I have used this `contact.php` form for a different website and it works fine. I read that the php code may now be deprecated but I'm not sure how to fix it.

This is the php code:

```
<?php

if(!$_POST) exit;

$email = $_POST['email'];


//$error[] = preg_match('/\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i',     $_POST['email']) ? '' : 'INVALID EMAIL ADDRESS';
if(!preg_match('/\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i',$email )){
$error.="Invalid email address entered";
$errors=1;
}
if($errors==1) echo $error;
else{
$values = array ('name','email','message');
$required = array('name','email','message');

$your_email = "dimasir@yahoo.com";
$email_subject = "New Message: ".$_POST['subject'];
$email_content = "new message:\n";

foreach($values as $key => $value){
  if(in_array($value,$required)){
    if ($key != 'subject' && $key != 'company') {
      if( empty($_POST[$value]) ) { echo 'PLEASE FILL IN REQUIRED FIELDS';     exit; }
    }
    $email_content .= $value.': '.$_POST[$value]."\n";
  }
}

if(@mail($your_email,$email_subject,$email_content)) {
    echo 'Message sent!'; 
} else {
    echo 'ERROR!';
}
}
?>
```

edit original  note****This is my HTML code:

```
                <form method="post" action="contact.php"> 
                  <input type="hidden" name="send" value="1" />
                    <fieldset>                      
                        <label>First Name </label>
                        <input name="" type="text" class="filed1" />
                        <label>Last Name</label>
                        <input name="" type="text" class="filed1" />
                            <label>Your Email  </label>
                        <input name="" type="text" class="filed1" />
                        <label>Company</label>
                        <input name="" type="text" class="filed1" />
                        <label>Message </label>
                        <textarea name="" cols="" rows="" ></textarea>
                        <input type="image" src="images/send.jpg" />

                    </fieldset>
              </form>
            </div>
            <!--  \ CONTACT BOX / -->

          </div>
```

Comment: Change `<label>Your Email  </label><input name="" type="text" class="filed1" />` into `<label>Your Email  </label><input name="email" type="text" class="filed1" />`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i check if user entering correct form of email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883694/how-can-i-check-if-user-entering-correct-form-of-email)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!preg_match('/\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i',$email )){
    $error.="Invalid email address entered";
    $errors=1;
}
```

Should be this:

```
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $error .= "Invalid email address entered";
    $errors = 1;
}
```

PHP has a built in function [filter_var()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php#example-4924) to validate email addresses which is more faster and accurate than using a regex.

Use this HTML code **(Make sure to fill out the rest of the attributes)**:

```
<label>First Name </label>
<input name="f_name" type="text" class="filed1" />
<label>Last Name</label>
<input name="l_name" type="text" class="filed1" />
    <label>Your Email  </label>
<input name="email" type="text" class="filed1" />
<label>Company</label>
<input name="company" type="text" class="filed1" />
<label>Message </label>
<textarea name="message" cols="" rows="" ></textarea>
<input type="image" src="images/send.jpg" />
```

Comment: I tried this and received error message Invalid email address....

Comment: @user1489550 do this `var_dump($email);` before you run the above code and post the output here.

Comment: sorry I need some help with this, where do I place the code? should it be on the contact.php?  if so, exactly where?

Comment: Place it right before the if statement

Comment: this is the message I received : NULL Invalid email address entered

Comment: OK, now try `var_dump($_POST);`, instead of the previous line

Comment: It means the value is not being submitted. Which means you are using GET not POST, or your form field name is not named `email` but something else. Please post your form HTML.

Comment: I suspect the person is using POST, but the value is not correct. Otherwise `if(!$_POST) exit;` would not pass

Comment: @LukasBijaminas true, however I've seen some strange code on the interwebz where people use POST and GET together in a form incorrectly, so just being general in my debugging since without the HTML form code, it's all speculation on our end.

Comment: I got the php code from Dreamtemplate.com...This is the result of the last coding change...array(3) { ["send"]=> string(1) "1" ["x"]=> string(2) "55" ["y"]=> string(2) "27" } Invalid email address entered

Comment: No email is being passed. As @crypticツ said, please post the HTML part.

Comment: I have tried to paste the code here but it is 61 characters too long...can I post it elsewhere? Thanks so much for helping me with this, by the way...

Comment: @user1489550 edit your original question and post it there.

Comment: I have now added the HTML to the lower portion of my original note.

Comment: @user1489550 none of your form fields have any names. Please correct your HTML.

Comment: Don't copy/paste code as 90% of the time the code will be wrong in some way or the other. Read up on HTML and basic PHP before attempting something like this.

Comment: I apologize, I am a newbie. The template was coded as it is. When I asked DreamTemplate.com for help they suggested a couple minor changes but they didn't help at all. Thank you for your time & efforts. I will try & figure this out.

Comment: My sincere thanks to you both :) Something so simple but it drove me crazy. I now have learned a lesson & that is to never trust a template 100 percent!

Answer (score 1):

Change your line that goes like

`if(!preg_match('/\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i',$email )){`

into

`if(!preg_match('/^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*
      @[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$/',$email )){`.

This should fix the problem.

If this doesn't work, try changing `$email = $_POST['email'];` into `$email = urldecode($_POST['email'])`;

Comment: Hi, Thanks for responding. I tried changing the preg match coding & I received Parse error: syntax error, unexpected contact.php on line 9. The coding change was on line 9. This was the line I replaced. I then changed line 9 back to the original and made the second change you suggested and received the Invalid email address entered error once again...Do you have any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I made a tiny change, please try now

Comment: You should not be using a regex for this as PHP has built-in support for validating an email address. Don't re-invent the wheel using an inefficient and inaccurate method.

Comment: @crypticツ I agree with your solution

Comment: I have tried the regex but I still receive the same error message. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: What kind of email address are you entering?

Comment: I have used several, one being rosiesweb@gmail.com

Comment: @crypticツ However `filter_var()` available as of **PHP 5.2.0**. I've encountered that some hosting providers do not support `filter_var` function, so that it isn't 100% reliable, say if you write a framework, CMS or the like. The best solution would be : `if ( function_exists('filter_var') ) { /* use filter_var() */ } else { /* use regex */  }`

Comment: @metal_fan if you are using anything less than 5.4 let alone less than 5.2 then you have some serious problems and should switch hosts. Support for PHP 5.3 will be dropped within a month or two when PHP 5.5 comes out.

Comment: No need to `urlencode()/urldecode()`. This will be done automatically by engine itself.

Comment: @metal_fan no it is not automatically done...yes, it does not need to be done in this case, but regardless it is not automatic.

Comment: @crypticツ I develop CMS/social networking services, which should be adopted for almost any hosting provider. I didn't say that I use php less than 5.4 :) emm.. yeah yeah, it will be dropped soon, but many hosting providers don't seem to care. Some of them still use < 5.2. You can check that by googling. It's a matter of code portability. (Which is important for CMS/frameworks)

Comment: @crypticツ oh, really? :) The globals like `$_COOKIE`, `$_GET`, `$_POST` automatically parsed by engine itself. But don't trust me, check this out: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: @metal_fan I was talking about urlencoding, as in what the above answer said.

Comment: @metal_fan PHP 5.2 came out in Nov 2 2006. If everyone used that logic, they would have spaghetti code in no time, not to mention if you support 5.2 why not 3.0? Because, you know someone might be running it. There is a limit to when it becomes irrational and making a systems requirement to say at least PHP versions that are supported by PHP.

Comment: @crypticツ yes, you were talking about urlencoding. I implied that both encoding and decoding will be done AUTOMATICALLY for superglobals, like $_GET, $_POST. A typical example is: The form element like, `<input type="text" name="foo" />` contains value, like, "O M G", when you echo it, you won't get "O%20M%20G" back. You'll get a "clean" result. Thus it has been encoded/decoded internally, true? Sure...

Comment: @crypticツ Yes, you're right PHP 5.2 came out in Nov 2 2006. "Spaghetti" or not, it depends on how EXACTLY a dev understand the OOP/SOLID/MVP/SoC and so on.. But listen, look at CodeIgniter, WordPress, Cake ... they are all still adopted for PHP 5.1 and don't use things like namespaces, traits... **THIS IS BECAUSE**, they want their code to be portable. And also, You can't really predict which PHP ver your customers/users will be using on. Take care :)

Comment: @metal_fan The encoding is done by the browser, decoding is done by the server. The above answer said to urlencode() the email, which is wrong in this instance as it would break the regex. Your comment does not point that out, but rather implies that the urlencode() is already done to it, which it is not otherwise the value would be encoded. Please learn how to write logical comments that make sense. I'm done arguing with you, I've had to do this with you in the past and it's a huge waste of my time. Btw you might want to lookup the min reqs for those frameworks. Good day, end of thread =o)

Comment: @crypticツ oh so lovely..1)The encoding is done by the browser, IN CASE if it was a `GET` request. [Query string]. Not POST. What about this one? Both Encoding and Decoding for POST will be done by Server-side app. I'd love to hear (with evidence), that I'm wrong. Write a CMS using TinyMCE & ajax for submission and you will fell it.2) Btw, min req for those frameworks, is PHP5.1 and most of them check whether `filter_var()` exists before calling it. The code which has been written for PHP5.1.x will work for future versions3)Oh,you already hate me and you're done arguing.. I'd better stop here:)